# Lens: combine children values (xml-lens)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have an xml that looks like this:

```xml
<Root>
  <V>
    <A>AAA</A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C>...</C>
  </V>
  <V>
    <A>BBB</A>
    <B>200</B>
    <C>...</C>
  </V>
</Root>
```

I need to get a list of `A` and `B` values (for example as a list of tuples):

```
[("AAA", 100), ("BBB", 200)]
```

Using [xlm-lens](https://github.com/fumieval/xml-lens) methods, I know how to get one field list:

```hs
As = doc ^.. root ... named "V" ... named "A" . text
```

The question is how to combine multiple fields (in the case of my task - "A" and "B")?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something easily supported because it's fragile in several ways. First off, the operation of combining two optics that work on the same value cannot be done lawfully if the two optics overlap. Of course, that doesn't mean it isn't offered [with notes about how it can violate the lens laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2/docs/Control-Lens-Unsound.html#v:lensProduct).

Second, `lensProduct` alone isn't enough. You've also got an implicit assumption that each `<V>` will contain exactly one `<A>` and exactly one `<B>`. There's no such restriction in XML in general, so `xml-lens` provides give you traversals rather than lenses. `lensProduct` doesn't type-check with traversals. This is kind of handy, because it's rather unclear what it should even do when there isn't exactly one matching element. Sure, you could say "take the cartesian product", but that may violate higher-level assumptions silently. In fact, I rather expect it would quickly fail the law of least surprise.

Still, if you're willing to make your code less safe, `lens` gives you [a function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:singular) to convert a traversal that's expected to have exactly one target into a lens.

I don't have xml-lens installed, but I believe this is an adequate demonstration:

```
ghci> let x = (10, ["ab", "cd", "ef"])
ghci> x ^.. _2 . traverse . (lensProduct (singular $ ix 0) (singular $ ix 1))
[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]

ghci> let y = (10, ["ab", "cd", "ef", "g"])
ghci> y ^.. _2 . traverse . (lensProduct (singular $ ix 0) (singular $ ix 1))
[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'),('g',*** Exception: singular: empty traversal
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Control/Lens/Traversal.hs:700:46 in lens-5.2-5baea74547b047869cdde9b7d52e4f741da162c6f70a1613022e059e88427e27:Control.Lens.Traversal
  singular, called at <interactive>:21:55 in interactive:Ghci15
```

Watch out there, as `singular` will crash your program if the value it's looking for doesn't exist.

This isn't exactly satisfying, but it's very hard to see how to do better within the constraints of confidence and clarity `lens` attempts to work within. Maybe some sort of function to give back the product of two folds would be useful, but it still would have clarity issues that would make it very hard to work confidently with.

(No longer my first choice, but preserved for completeness and as another option. See the edit below.) For what it's worth, I think this is best solved by first extracting all the `<V>` elements from the document, and then mapping an extraction function with explicit failure handling over each. At that point, you can decide if you want to discard the failures or propagate them upward. Some things just don't fit into lens's single-pass paradigm.

**Edit:**

As DanielWagner points out in the comments, you can do a little bit better, and at least get rid of the crashing case:

```
ghci> let x = (10, ["ab", "cd", "ef"])
ghci> x ^.. _2 . traverse . (lensProduct (partsOf $ ix 0) (partsOf $ ix 1))
[("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f")]

ghci> let y = (10, ["ab", "cd", "ef", "g"])
ghci> y ^.. _2 . traverse . (lensProduct (partsOf $ ix 0) (partsOf $ ix 1))
[("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f"),("g","")]
```

You can replace the use of `singular` with the use of `partsOf`. This changes the type of the result slightly. (Note that the return type is now `[([Char],[Char])]` instead of `[(Char,Char)]`. This will no longer crash, and leaves handling unexpected numbers of child elements to the caller in a useful way. I like it a lot better than using `singular`, because now the type at least warns you about potential errors you'll have to handle. This is good enough that I'd use it in preference to my previous suggestion above.

Comment: Proposal for something that should be law-abiding: could one extract all the `V` nodes, then for each `V` node extract a pair of lists, one each for `A` and `B` nodes? So the final type would look something like `[([A], [B])]`. What would that look like with lens?

Comment: @DanielWagner That still would depend on non-law-abiding pieces, like `lensProduct`. But yes, I think you could use `partsOf` in there.  That's a good point. I'll confirm and add it to the answer.

Comment: Ok, I tried this:`doc ^.. root ... named "W" ... (lensProduct (partsOf $ named "A" . text) (partsOf $ named "B" . text))` it giver really strange and verbose product of many also empty tuples,

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Can you add a minimal example of that code going wrong using definitions in either ghci or a file? There are so many things that could be going on, it's important to see what input you're handling.

Comment: I've put in past been working module with xml parsing it requires `lens, xml-lens, text, raw-strings-qq` packages https://pastebin.com/sg8aJAzX